# GWT: How to catch what code overrides the CSS cursor value. Or why it overrides?

Tags: java, css, gwt, cursor

I have `ScrollPanel` in UI. And I want to dynamically change cursor over this panel when user does something special. However, somewhere in the code (I have tried searching for `"default"` (with or without quotes) over all the files (including CSS and Java) in the project, also I 've searched over for `Cursor.DEFAULT` mentions — no such line that changes it to default one) it is *periodically* changed to DEFAULT value for this panel, right in the element's style.  That's why even overriding with `!important` doesn't works. So I think to blame GWT in this case.

Am I wrong in searching for the reason or can I somehow debug this concrete change of the cursor, or it is the CSS to blame (conditional breakpoint matches too much times for `Style.setCursor()`, again it can be changed with `setAttribute`).

I can change cursor for the inner div, but it will be a Hack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the reason it happened, of course it was a fault in my code (I found it in search but thought that it is not the reason). However, the way to monitor who changes the CSS properties dynamically may be the important thing